# (React JS) Internal HTML Links when clicked scrolls the page to desired position but immediately update the URL and loads the default app page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

When I click `<a href="#">Go to Top</a>`, it scrolls the page to the top but then it updates the URL to `http://localhost:6061/#` and loads the default app page as http://localhost:6061/# is not defined in the router.

How do I avoid updating the URL when it is just an internal link?

Comment: `onClick={e => e.preventDefault()}`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable a link in reactjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755802/how-to-disable-a-link-in-reactjs)

Comment: @evolutionxbox: onClick is called before the href, and thus it prevents the scroll of the page with URL update as well. Basically, it prevents any action.

Comment: Consider using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo?